# Vue 3 reactivity of a primitive ref passed as a prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

While playing with Vue 3 reactivity I incountred a behaviour that I couldn't explain.

I created a `ref` of a primitive. Checking `isRef` on it returns obviously `true`. But when passed to a child component as a `prop`, `isRef()` and also `isReactive()` return `false`. Why ?

Also, even if they both return `false`, the watcher of this prop I added in the child component is triggered if the value changes. How could it trigger if the watched value is not a `ref` nor `reactive` ?

Here is a code snippet for both the parent and the child :

Parent.vue

```
let foo = ref(0);
function changeFoo() {
  foo.value++;
}
  
console.log("parent check is reactive?", isReactive(foo)); // retruns false
console.log("parent check is ref?", isRef(foo)); // retruns true

watch(foo, (value, oldValue) => {
  console.log("foo changing from", oldValue, "to ", value);
});
```

Child.vue

```
const props = defineProps<{
  foo: number;
}>();

console.log("child check is reactive?",isReactive(props), isReactive(props.foo)); // returns true false
console.log("child check is ref ?",isRef(props), isRef(props.foo)); // returns false false // Question 1: Why props.foo is not a Ref ?
  
watch(props, (value, oldValue) => {
  console.log("props changing from", oldValue, " to ", value);
});
 
watch(()=>props.foo, (value, oldValue) => {
  // Question 2: Why this Watcher detects changes of "foo" without it being a ref nor reactive ?
  console.log("props.foo changing from ", oldValue, " to ", value);
});
```

And a link to Vue SFC Playground [here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Bonus question :
When `foo` is passed to a composable used in the child component, the watcher inside the composable is not triggered unless we pass `foo` via a toRef but we don't need this additional step if `foo` is a ref/reactive object. Why primitives needs this addition step ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when passed to a child component as a prop, isRef() and also isReactive() return false.

You're only telling half the story here, as your own comment actually indicates:

```js
console.log("child check is reactive?",isReactive(props), isReactive(props.foo)); // returns true false
```

`isReactive(props)` *does* return true, because the entire `props` object (which wraps `foo`) is reactive.  Any update the parent makes to `foo`, gets passed down to the Child as an updated `props` object.  It's true `props.foo` is not a ref/reactive, because it doesn't need to be.  As long as `props` is reactive, `props.foo` will update

The watcher is able to activate on changes to `props.foo` because you're actually using special syntax where you pass in a "getter" to the watch specifically meant for watching the *property of a reactive object* (in your case: props). There's an example in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#basic-example) that says the same thing.

If you ever needed to assign `props.foo` to it's own reactive variable, say to pass to a composable, that's where  toRef can be used.

```js
// reactive but not synced with props.foo
const newFoo = ref(props.foo)

// reactive AND synced with props.foo
const newFoo = toRef(props, 'foo')
```

As I indicated with the above comments, if you make a new variable with just `ref`, it'll be reactive, but it won't be synced with it's source property, i.e. the first `newFoo` won't reactively update when `props.foo` updates, but the second `newFoo` will. This is also explained well in the [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am sure that I am closer to understanding the behavior. If prop is  always reactive and that's why changes of foo are detected, why do we need to make foo a ref in the parent ? We can declate it as a raw let foo = 0 and pass it as a prop that will be reactive. I tried that but it did not work. The watcher is not triggered after modifing foo in the parent. It seems logic since foo is not a ref but I can't understand why it's diffrent form my first example as they are both isRef false and both are properties of a reactive object 'props'

Comment: if `foo` isn't reactive in the parent, then the parent won't know to reactively update the child's prop based on `foo` updating.  `props.foo` is reactive in the child, but it's waiting for reactive updates from the parent that will never come.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. I ll mark it as the correct one. But, it's just lacking an answer to my first question "Question 1: Why props.foo is not a Ref ?" and the answer is that refs passed as props are unwraped. it's the aquivalent of passing foo.value so in my case the plain raw primitive is passed to the child component and not the ref object this is why isRef(props.foo) is false inside the child

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that in the child, 'props.foo' is reactive when used within the setup/script (ie not in the template according to my playing arounds) but 'foo' isnt reactive if prop is destructured (ie `const {foo} = props`).

But you should do this by using the `toRef` function ( `const foo = toRef(props,'foo')`) to be extra sure **OR** make the entire props object reactive with `toRefs` (`const reactiveProp = toRefs(props)`) then refer to it with `reactiveProp.foo` (and it will still be reactive even if you destructure it) **OR** use `computed` eg `const reactiveFoo = computed(()=>props.foo)`.
You can play around (and see my commented notes here [Vue Props Reactivity Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-weh79m?file=src/components/Child.vue)).

Frustrated me for a while cos this is unlike React.js (which I had been using for a long time), the props are reactive (even if destructured). See test here [React Props Reactivity](https://react-uhmt6j.stackblitz.io)